Is Lebesgue outer measure semicontinous?
Let $m^*$ be the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Endow $2^{[0,1]}$ with the product topology, which is Hausdorff compact. Identify it with the set of all subsets of $[0,1]$. Is the map $$m^*:2^{[0,1]}\to \mathbb{R}, \, A\mapsto m^*(A)$$ lower semicontinuous?  The question is inspired by Continuity from below for Lebesgue outer measure.

Perhaps include the definition (or link) to "lower semicontinuous" for a set-function.

Its domain is a family of sets.  (That's what I mean by "set-function".)
